# open command sets RTS and DTR by default

Tags: tty, ftdi

I connect via FTDI to an STM32 via my own application written on Ubuntu 14.04.1.
I figured out one problem with simply opening the tty like:

```
/* Open File Descriptor */
int fd = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY );
```

The problem here is, that `open()` sets DTR and RTS by default.
That means that the STM always do a reset when I execute the `open()` command, but actually I just want to read from the port.
The following code won't do it either:

```
int fd = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDONLY| O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY );
```

Is there any way to set RTS and DTR in advance?

Comment: @simgineer STM32: ST-Microelectronics 32-bit ARM Cortex Micro Controller Unit